# How to find the articles from the XIV Ordinary General Assembly of Synod of Bishops (Synod of the Family) and the votes on them?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, same-sex-marriage, family, synodal-path

Frédéric Martel in his book [*In the Closet of the Vatican*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1472966147) has the following remarks on the [Synod of the Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Ordinary_General_Assembly_of_the_Synod_of_Bishops):

> In fact, a ‘liberal* majority emerged from the Synod, but the quorum
> required for the adoption of the controversial articles, which
> required two-thirds of the votes, was missing. Three paragraphs out of
> 62 were therefore rejected » and they were the most to the point. The
> pope didn’t get his quorum. Francis’s revolutionary project on the
> family and homo­ sexuality was defeated.

**Is there any source where I can find the texts of those 3 rejected paragraphs and the votes taken on them?** I am especially interested to check whether all 3 paragraphs indeed gathered the majority votes and were not included in the final document due only to the supermajority requirement. I have read some reviews about the book cited above and they mention many fact checking failures. So, the quoted

> 'liberal' majority

may be a metaphor and may not mean the majority of votes for the specific paragraphs.

I am aware of the [www.synod.va](http://www.synod.va/content/synod/en.html).  The website has the *instrumentum laboris* and similar documents but I can not find the proceedings (transactions) and the votes. AFAIK, the synodal assemblies are not closed as opposed to the Ecumenical Councils.  (I heard there are about 50+ volume publications of the [Second Vatican Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Vatican_Council), therefore the notion that Vatican II was closed is quite dubious).

**Question to be clarified**: While the question (as it stands) seems to be legitimate, most likely Frédéric Martel talked about the [III Extraordinary Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Extraordinary_General_Assembly_of_the_Synod_of_Bishops), which was the preparatory synodal assembly before the [XIV ordinary assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteenth_Ordinary_General_Assembly_of_the_Synod_of_Bishops).

Comment: It looks like the [www.synod.va](http://www.synod.va/content/synod/en.html) website no longer returns an HTTP 503 error.